# How to get value of variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row data as

For EACH row I want to get the value of tkID i.e. the query should return me 245764, how to do that in SQL Server ? The other string will always remain same, only tkID will be different.

I have tried `SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE SUBSTRING(1,)...`Please help

```
Table
      SAMPLE DATA
      PERSON

     ID         TEXT
    1            <com.innovation.jsp.beans.structTaskContext
        obj-name="tkDetails" descriptionKey="B.Tk.Undefined"
        tkID="245764" abc="1"....


    2            <com.innovation.jsp.beans.structTaskContext
        obj-name="tkDetails" descriptionKey="B.Tk.Undefined"
        tkID="245765" abc="2".....
```

Output should be:

```
     ID            tkID
     1             245764
     2             245765
```

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Please post some sample data from the table and your desired result

Comment: I have added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
declare @text nvarchar(1000)='<com.innovation.jsp.beans.structTaskContext
    obj-name="tkDetails" descriptionKey="B.Tk.Undefined"
    tkID="245765" abc="2".....'
```

If the above format is same for all records

```
select substring(@text, charindex('tkID=', @text)+6,charindex('abc=', @text)-(charindex('tkID=', @text)+8))
```

If tckId is of length 6

```
select substring(@text, charindex('tkID=', @text)+6,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX`, `RIGHT` and `LEFT` string functions.

**Query**

```
select  left((right(@str, len(@str) -  patindex('%tkID="%', @str) - 5)), 
        charindex('"', 
        (right(@str, len(@str) -  patindex('%tkID="%', @str) - 5)), 1) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #b
(
                     ID    int,     TEXT varchar(max)
                     )
                     insert into #b values
(1,'<com.innovation.jsp.beans.structTaskContext
    obj-name="tkDetails" descriptionKey="B.Tk.Undefined"
    tkID="245764" abc="1"....'),


(2,'<com.innovation.jsp.beans.structTaskContext
    obj-name="tkDetails" descriptionKey="B.Tk.Undefined"
    tkID="245765" abc="2".....')

    SELECT SUBSTRING(text, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', text), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', text + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    text) + 1) AS Number from #b
```

output

```
Number
245764
245765
```